# Set targeted runtime in Maven app

Tags: maven, runtime, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm developing Maven apps with IBM Rational Application Developer and deploying EARs on Websphere Application Server 8.5. When I generate EAR file using maven-ear-plugin and try to deploy it on WAS, Eclipse complains about targeted runtime not being set.

How can I set targeted runtime during build?

Comment: I may be missing something but isn't this something you set in eclipse/RAD as part of the project's metadata? Have you tried setting it like in https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjtargetserver.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237751/unable-to-associate-project-with-a-runtime-server-in-eclipse-ide, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985980/removing-the-apache-tomcat-runtime-from-a-project-in-eclipse, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html#exercise-create-a-java-web-project-in-eclipse-using-maven

Comment: @RyanDawson Yes, you're right, I am setting it like this. But I'm looking for some other solution to set targeted runtime for example with some kind of Maven plugin or something similar.